# Physics logo is almost invisible on the Site Rooms button in chat

Tags: bug, design, chat

It's hot accent color on accent color action:

[image]

See it in the top right corner of [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-coupling)

Comment: Somehow I'd never noticed that...

Comment: I thought that was extra space!!!